# Gcloud SDK issue

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, path, sdk, gcloud

I am trying to configure gcloud sdk, below is the process i followed :

1. Installed Google Cloud SDK for windows bundle with Python Version 204.0.0.0
2. Updated Environment Variables:
   GCLOUD_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google Cloud SDK for Windows-204"
   PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google Cloud SDK for Windows-204\bin"
3. Initialized gcloud configuration via CMD
   C:>gcloud init

Got an error which says you must have python installed and on your path and as an alternative you may also set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable- - - - - - I have python installed and set the path to CLOUDSDK_PYTHON

I've set path to python in my PATH as well.

But still getting same error

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: The Google Cloud SDK Windows installer includes Python. Remove the changes you made, uninstall and then install the SDK. Do not deselect the built-in Python package.

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Try to improve that. Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments. To highlight apps' names or interface, use a **bold** (`**` brackets) or *italic* (`*` brackets) font. To start from a new line use *double space* at the end of the line - the question'll be way more clear than using *Enter* everywhere. Adding some `:` would be nice too.